# std::future no_state exception vs assertion

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, future, assert

The way I understand things, `assert`s should be used to check for programming errors and document conditions that should never happen, and exceptions should be used for runtime errors beyond the programmer's control (for example, getting a `key_not_found` response from a database)

So then why is `std::future_errc::no_state` a thing?  An exception with that value can only be thrown when a future is accessed that does not have valid state.  Which is something the programmer can control.  Why not just encourage implementations to abort from a failed assertion or abort when this happens? Is there a situation where a user might be able to recover from a no state exception?

For example if they return a future that has not been fetched from a call to `std::promise::get_future()` then it will not have any valid state.  Or calling `get()` on a future twice.

Answer (score 1):

`assert`ions are *mostly* a debugging/while-you-are-developing feature. They are *usually* left out when compiling release versions of code. So, while they are nice to have and can document invariants and other stuff while you develop the code (and help you catch bugs), you cannot depend on them being enabled always.
On the other hand, `std::future_errc::no_state` is *not* just a debug thing and will always be there (unless of course you are one of those people who build with exceptions (and rtti) disabled - but in that case I have nothing to offer and no sympathy).

Comment: But the standard does not require the exception to be thrown. In that case why not just recommend libraries to abort (which will not be affected by debug builds) instead of throwing?

Comment: @Curious "But the standard does not require the exception to be thrown" - You need to ask the question of why that is so to the standards committee.

Comment: that wasn't a question. As for why I'm asking. I just want to understand why the decision was made to have that exception in the first place. If there is an actual place where i should be trying to catch this exception in my code then i would like to do that.

Comment: @Curious and whom other than the members of the committee will be able to answer why that decision was made?

Comment: People who use this feature?

Comment: I would like to add that [`std::future_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_error) is a [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) which represents a logic error on the part of the programmer. This is what you describe `assert` is for. `std::logic_error` is essentially the standard library way of reporting assertion failures. It's also why many developers avoid catching them.